# Why is my gremlin.net gremlin client not working with azure cosmos graph db

Tags: c#, azure, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinnet

I've set up a serverless azure cosmos graph db account and now I'm trying to connect to it using the following code:

```
.AddSingleton(s =>
    {
        var connectionPool = new ConnectionPoolSettings
        {
            MaxInProcessPerConnection = 32,
            PoolSize = 4,
            ReconnectionAttempts = 4,
            ReconnectionBaseDelay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
        };
        var server = new GremlinServer("<project-name>.documents.azure.com", 443, true, "/dbs/<DatabaseName>/colls/<GraphName>", "<primary key>");
        return new GremlinClient(server, connectionPoolSettings: connectionPool);
    })
```

The GremlinClient throws an Exception with the message

> The server returned status code '200' when status code '101' was expected.

I'm using Gremlin.Net 3.6.0 with NET 6
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was resolved by changing the uri from

```
<project-name>.documents.azure.com
```

to

```
<project-name>.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/gremlin-api-faq#why-am-i-getting-the--websocketexception--the-server-returned-status-code--200--when-status-code--101--was-expected--error-

Answer (score 1):

If you were connecting well with earlier versions of Gremlin.Net you might want to revert. [According to their website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/graph/gremlin-support) their supported version is 3.4.6. While later versions along 3.4.x might work, it might require more configuration (like, I think you might have to switch the serializer as I dont think CosmosDB supports the GraphBinary serializer) and you'd have to take care to not  use certain features that newer versions of TinkerPop have that 3.4.6 did not.